# Error(3,4): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'UPD_PLAGE_SAL'

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
 `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE upd_plage_sal
 (p_jobid  IN   jobs.job_id%TYPE,
  p_minsal  IN   jobs.max_salary%TYPE,
  p_maxsal  IN   jobs.min_salary%TYPE)
  AS
  BEGIN
       UPDATE   jobs
       SET max_salary = p_maxsal, min_salary = p_minsal 
       WHERE job_id = p_jobid 
       AND max_salary < p_maxsal or min_salary > p_minsal;
END upd_plage_sal;


---Trigger

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_sal_range
AFTER UPDATE OF salary ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   upd_plage_sal(:NEW.job_id, :NEW.salary);
END;`
```

It's a number in an homework that I cant resolve.

> Error(3,4): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
> 'UPD_PLAGE_SAL'

I got this error

the goal is to make a trigger that will update the max_salary or min_salary of HR table of a specific job_id if the salary of an employee is change below or above the min or max. Am I far from the solution? plz help

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Product specific code above.)

Comment: sql dev oraclee

Comment: Error text quite clear: compare your procedure declaration and procedure call. Also your query will update maximum salary if new minimum is less than current minimum

Comment: I know thats the goal but i just dont get the error still do i have to declare min and max?

Comment: Your calling statement for upd_plage_sal is passing 2 parameters, job_id and salary. But that procedure is defined to take 3 parameters.  By definition that is the wrong number of parameters. BTW that procedure updates both min_salary **and** max_salary every time. That does not seem consistent with your goal which would be to update min_salary **or** max_salary.